# Given two linear transformations, find the preimage of a given point for the composite transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

If someone could run quickly through the theory and methods on this it would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

> Let $f: \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$ be reﬂection in the line $y = x$ and let
>      $g: \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$ be clockwise rotation through $90^\circ$ around the origin.
>
> Find the point $v = (x,y) \in\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(g(v)) = (−3,−2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ and $g$ are both invertible, so to find $v$ such that $f(g(v))=(-3,-2)$, you can just invert the transformations one at a time:

$$fg(v)=(-3,-2)\\
\iff g(v)=f^{-1}((-3,-2))\\
\iff v=g^{-1}f^{-1}((-3,-2))
$$

Naturally, $f^{-1}$ is just $f$ itself, since reflections are their own inverses, and $g^{-1}$ is the *counterclockwise* rotation by $90^\circ$.

Thus $f^{-1}((-3,-2))=(-2,-3)$ and $g^{-1}f^{-1}((-3,-2))=g^{-1}((-2,-3))=(3,-2)$.

If you are familiar with transformations via matrices (acting on the left of column vectors) then you can check that

The matrix for $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

and the matrix for $g$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and for $g^{-1}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. The composition $g^{-1}f^{-1}$ via matrix multiplication gives $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.